# How to handle async data with ngOnInit

Tags: angular

Template:

```
<h5 class="card-title">{{profile.company}}</h5>
```

ProfileComponent:

```
private getRouteParams;
public profile;

ngOnInit() {
    this.getRouteParams = this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this._customerService.getCustomer(params.id)
          .subscribe(data => this.profile = data[0])
    });
 }
```

Got the following error:

```
inline template:3:33 caused by: Cannot read property 'company' of undefined
```

I think it's because the template is loading faster then the ngOnInit? How can i prevent this?

I log data[0] to console. Everything looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
private getRouteParams;
public profile:any = {
company: '';
};

ngOnInit() {
    this.getRouteParams = this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this._customerService.getCustomer(params.id)
          .subscribe(data => this.profile = data[0])
    });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I prevent this using a a interface for profile?

Comment: is it maybe better to use async pipe or profile?.company in the template?

Comment: The Angular team has advised that you don't use filter pipes in Angular2, as it is an extremely expensive operation. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#no-filter-pipe